# How to label the line intersection with the Axis and remove the ticks in parallel coordinates d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to visualize categorical data using parallel coordinates in d3.js and want the intersection of line and axis to show the category name. Refer the below Image.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leUyA.png)

Below is my current code.
I'm using d3 v3.4

```
d3.csv("/static/testQuantifized.csv", function(error, coffee) {
    x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(coffee[0]).filter(function(d) {
    // console.log(d);
    if(d == "" ||d == "Country of Origin" ||d == "Variety" ||d == "Processing Method" || d == "Altitude" || d == "Grading Date" || d == "Altitude" || d == "Balance" || d =="uniformity" || d == "Clean Cup" || d =="Sweetness" || d == "Defects" || d == "Total Cup Points" || d =="Moisture Percentage" || d =="Category One Defects" || d =="Quakers" || d == "Color" || d == "Category Two Defects" || d == "Expiration") return false;
    // if(d == "Country of Origin" || "Variety" || "Processing Method") {
    //     y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
    //       .domain(coffee.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
    //       .rangePoints([h, 0]);

    // }
    else if(d == "Aroma" || "Flavor" || "Aftertaste" || "Acidity" || "Body" || "Overall") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain(d3.extent(coffee, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
          .range([h, 0]);
    }

    return true;
}));

  // Add an axis and title.
  g.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
    .append("svg:text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(String);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for labeling, add ordinal scale:

```
var y = {};
y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(coffee.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
    .rangePoints([height, 0]);
```

To remove the ticks from the axis, you should define the axis like this:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left").tickSize(0).tickFormat("");
```

When you append the axis to your graph, do it this way:

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); });
```

In this code, replace d with the relevant column name from your dataset for the categorical data. The 'height' refers to the height of your chart.

Hope this helps!